# Capturing only a portion of canvas with .todataurl Javascript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can capture a full canvas with .todataurl without a problem.  But I do not see or know if there is anyway to capture only a portion of the canvas and save that to image.

e.i. Mr. Potatohead script draws hats, hands feet faces etc etc. mixed all over the canvas and you can drag and drop them onto the mr potato in the center of the canvas.  Press a button save the image of mr potato looking all spiffy to jpg for you.  Without all the extra hats/feet/faces in the image.

I have resigned myself to the fact that this is impossible based on everything I've read.  But you folks have proven to be smarter than google (or atleast google in my hands) a few times so i am taking a shot.

Sorry no code to post this time... unless you want this:

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById("mrp");
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=800, height=600");
```

But that is just the example of dataurl i am working off of.. and it works outside of the fact it doesnt cap just the mr potato

My fallback is to pass the image to php and work with it there to cut out everything i dont want then pass it back.

**EDIT**

tmcw had a method for doing this. Not sure if its the way it SHOULD be done but it certainly works.

```
document.getElementById('grow').innerHTML="<canvas id='dtemp' ></canvas>";
var SecondaryCanvas  = document.getElementById("dtemp");
var SecondaryCanvas_Context = SecondaryCanvas.getContext ("2d");
SecondaryCanvas_Context.canvas.width = 600;
SecondaryCanvas_Context.canvas.height = 600;
var img = new Image();
img.src = MainCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
SecondaryCanvas_Context.drawImage(img, -400, -300);
var du = SecondaryCanvas.toDataURL();
window.open(du, "toDataURL() image", "width=600, height=600");
document.getElementById('grow').innerHTML="";
```

grow is an empty span tag,  SecondaryCanvas is a var created just for this
SecondaryCanvas_Context is the getcontext of SecondaryCanvas
img created just to store the .toDataURL() of the main canvas containing the Mr. PotatoHead
drawImage with negative (-) offsets to move image of MainCanvas so that just the portion i want is showing.
Then cap the new canvas that was just created and open a new window with the .png

on and if you get an error from the script saying security err 18 its because you forgot to rename imgTop to img with the rest of the variables you copy pasted and chrome doesnt like it when you try to save local content images like that.

Comment: That's some crazy code you just wrote.  The secondary canvas doesn't need to be attached to the document, and you should use document.createElement rather than your crazy empty span innerHTML dance.

Comment: @david well the empty span was there for another reason i just re purposed it so i could quickly test this.. you are right though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new Canvas object of a specific size, use drawImage to copy a specific part of your canvas to a specific area of the new one, and use toDataURL() on the new canvas.

Comment: oh have got to love the simple answers i did not even think of that.  Will test now then update

Comment: Gunna need a minute its throwing an error when i try to do that sec err 18 when i try to do todataurl the second time

Answer (score 14):

Here's a method that uses an off-screen canvas:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = desiredWidth;
canvas.height = desiredHeight;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(originalCanvas,x,y,w,h,0,0,desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
result = canvas.toDataURL()
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more efficient (and maybe a cleaner) way of extracting part of the image:

```
// x,y are position in the original canvas you want to take part of the image
// desiredWidth,desiredHeight is the size of the image you want to have
// get raw image data
var imageContentRaw = originalCanvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(x,y,desiredWidth,desiredHeight);
// create new canvas
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
// with the correct size
canvas.width = desiredWidth;
canvas.height = desiredHeight;
// put there raw image data
// expected to be faster as tere are no scaling, etc
canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(imageContentRaw, 0, 0);
// get image data (encoded as bas64)
result = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0)
```

Answer (score -3):

you can give left,top,width and Height parameters to toDataURL function.. Here is the code to get data image depending on the object on canvas.

```
mainObj = "your desired Object"; // for example canvas._objects[0];

var image   = canvas.toDataURL({ left: mainObj.left, top:mainObj.top,
    width: mainObj.width*mainObj.scaleX, height: mainObj.height*mainObj.scaleY});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: I don't see this in the API docs; what browser does this work in?

Comment: @Charlie, none. This is not part of the web-API at all. Maybe some lib... If you need some working code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033357/how-do-i-extract-a-portion-of-an-image-in-canvas-and-use-it-as-background-image/35033622#35033622

Comment: I added a simplified version of that answer here ;)